# how to get images as wel as data from XML file in NSURL as asynchronous download in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

i have an XML file as url where the file contains like this,

```
<Products>
<products id="1">
<name>product1</name>
<price>$150</price>
<img>http://www.myimage.com/Main_pic.png</img>
</products>
</Products>
```

Now using NSXMLParser i can retrieve the data and the image but after i get those data am not understanding how to store in NSMutableArray or NSDictionary. Also i tried to implement lazyloading asynchronous image download from [Lazy Loading Table Images Asynchronous Downloading from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html). But i failed to load the images. Do we have any alternative for aynchronous loading.

Kindly describe me in detail about,

1. how to store a data retieved from url XML file in aysnchronous downloading.
2. how to separate data and image.
3. how to implement those in UIImage and data to view in iPhone.

**EDITED**

for better understanding i need the data and the image like below picture and not in the table view.
[image: Sample Picture]

**EDITED-2**
By using the lazyloading parsing i modified according to my content here the code for your reference,

```
- (void)main{
self.workingArray = [NSMutableArray array];
self.workingPropertyString = [NSMutableString string];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataToParse];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
if (![self isCancelled]){
self.completionHandler(self.workingArray);}
self.workingArray = nil;
self.workingPropertyString = nil;
self.dataToParse = nil;}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Products"]){
self.workingEntry = [[egsLists alloc] init];}
storingCharacterData = [elementsToParse containsObject:elementName];}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
if (self.workingEntry){
if (storingCharacterData){
NSString *trimmedString = [workingPropertyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
[workingPropertyString setString:@""];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:sIDStr]){
self.workingEntry.ProductID = trimmedString;}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:sImageStr]){
self.workingEntry.img = trimmedString;}}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Products"]){
[self.workingArray addObject:self.workingEntry];
self.workingEntry = nil;}}}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
if (storingCharacterData){
[workingPropertyString appendString:string];}}
```

Comment: please check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533244/how-to-fix-a-slow-scrolling-table-view/13533318#13533318

Comment: can you please post the xml parsing methods that you implemented ?

Comment: @midhun i have posted the parsing code which is modified from apple lazyloading images sample code

Comment: what is `storingCharacterData` and `elementsToParse` ?

Comment: storingCharacterData is BOOL and elementsToParse is NSArray. i used the sample lazzyloading sample from apple for more info you can see this link [link] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_ParseOperation_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Classes_ParseOperation_h-DontLinkElementID_9[/link] these two are inside ParseOperation.h and .m files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a `NSObject` Class say `DataClass`

// create objects for your data in `DataClass.h` And `Synthesize` them in `DataClass.m`

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

DataClass *mydata=[[DataClass alloc]init];

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"]) 
    {
mydata.idvalue=[currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) 
    {
mydata.namevalue=[currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"price"]) 
    {
mydata.pricevalue=[currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]) 
    {
mydata.imgLink=[currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}


[myArray addObject:mydata];



}
```

After That When You Need you can Retrive the Data From Array if you are Using `TableView`

then in your `CellForRowAtindexPath` method use the following:

```
DataClass *mydata=[[DataClass alloc]init];
mydata=[myarray objectAtindex:indexPath.row];

cell.textlabel.text=mydata.nameValue;
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:mydata.imglink]]];
```

You can Use [LazyTableImages SampleCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple for Loading Images.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

For Complete XML parsing [See the Tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/09/parsing-xml-in-an-iphone-app-tutorial/) or use Below Code:

Source : http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/09/parsing-xml-in-an-iphone-app-tutorial/

```
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://opentestdrive.com/Products.xml"]];

        // Perform request and get JSON as a NSData object


        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];


        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;


        NSLog(@"responseString=%@", responseString);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (conn)
        {
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        }
        else
        {
        }



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}


- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"imgName"]) 
    {
        //if you Taking any NSObject Class then Alloc init here.
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"name"]) 
    {
        namelable.text=currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"price"]) 
    {
        pricelabel.text = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"imgName"]) 
    {
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:currentNodeContent]]];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

Comment: `imageWithData:` is not a good method for binding images to tableView. It'll make your application unresposive sometimes

Comment: Yes i know i Just Given an Idea And informed To Use LazyTableimages check My answer.

Comment: ya siba i tried using the same lazytable images sample from apple i modified the code and tried for sample, with NSLog i can confirm it retrieves xml file from url but it shows the data and the images in it as null. i think its not parsing. can you help me in this i had edited my question for better understanding

Comment: Can you Post Your  NSLog Console output Here ?

Comment: From connection:
ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://myimage.com/Products.xml
From parsing:
  PARSE <NSXMLParser: 0x7135240>
Verifying data:
storing character data 0
storing character data 0
storing character data 1
storing character data 0
storing character data 1
storing character data 0
storing character data 1

Comment: Thanks a lot siba ill try it and let you know if i get the output as desired.

Comment: siba i go an error after i use UIImage *first = [UIImage imageNamed:@"78e0ff18-9f8c-4c5f-a446-1fed3d862e21_320.jpg"];in viewDidLoad(), i tried to get the objects with this code, **egsBase *currentImage = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];** here egsBase is where i declared the UIImage to connect with UIImageView and xmlParser is class in that tweets is storing objects from parser. The **objectAtIndex:indexPath.row** am getting error like **Use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'; did you mean 'NSIndexPath'?** how to solve this kindly guide me

Comment: instead of `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` use `objectAtIndex:0` Because `indexPath.row` is used in case of **TableView**.

Comment: Thanks a lot siba i got the expected output since am new for iphone struggling lot can i have your mailid if you wish if i have doubts i can contact through that. Once again thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Sure Give your mail ID i will send you a Test mail.